# Java - sometimes return NaN when calculating Mahalanobis distance

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mahalanobis

I use org.apache.mahout.common.distance.MahalanobisDistanceMeasure to calculate the distance between rows in a matrix and the mean vector, but it sometimes returns NaN. I tried to debug and it seems that a NullPointerException is thrown in the Object class. But for other rows everything is fine. I'd be grateful if someone could give me some guidance.

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import org.apache.commons.math.MathException;
import org.apache.mahout.common.distance.MahalanobisDistanceMeasure;
import org.apache.mahout.math.*;
import org.apache.mahout.math.Matrix;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix;
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.correlation.Covariance;
import org.apache.commons.math.distribution.ChiSquaredDistributionImpl;

public class FindMultivariateOutliers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "VIC_20160401_201606301.csv";
        double[][] data = extractRealData(readCSV(url), 3);
        double[][] dataSet = new double[30][49];
        for (int i = 30; i < 60; i++) {
            dataSet[i-30] = data[i];
        }

        double[] mean = calculateMeanVector(dataSet);
        Vector meanVector = new DenseVector(mean);
        Matrix covarianceMatrix = covarianceMatrix(dataSet);

        MahalanobisDistanceMeasure measure = new MahalanobisDistanceMeasure();
        measure.setMeanVector(meanVector);
        measure.setCovarianceMatrix(covarianceMatrix);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
            DenseVector ve = new DenseVector(dataSet[i]);
            double x = measure.distance(dataSet[centroid(dataSet)[0]][centroid(dataSet)[1]],meanVector,ve);
            System.out.println(i+" "+x);
        }
}
```

Outputs:

```
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 1.3382137932701006
3 5.140281428741069
4 5.448118335171329
5 4.658774790167001
6 3.055235041048766
7 5.577659807980593
8 2.9899726295069784
9 6.095988936666251
10 5.188517209151716
11 3.2929774499538014
12 5.090550175124932
13 5.801822265633947
14 4.714239296215186
15 5.02905587450129
16 4.981122780626051
17 5.195044166268684
18 5.325097238194922
19 4.7899888250142375
20 5.506442897174045
21 5.266585564849615
22 5.403384368592266
23 4.110229775894713
24 5.960687924915147
25 4.5745629099807745
26 5.0580441561885205
27 5.146058878694013
28 5.1375323540721425
29 3.7919178679466015
```

centroid()is a method that calculate centroid of a matrix, returns int[2](first element is x coordinate and the second is y).
dataSet is the matrix I'm focusing on.

Comment: Can you provide a verifiabl example? Your program is reading data from a file and we unfortunately don't have that file. Maybe just extract the offending data set and put it in the code?

Comment: @LukeLee The data have 49 dimensions so it's hard to provide an example. I updated the output of my codes, you can have a look.

Comment: If you're not clear on what `NaN` represents as distinct from positive/negative infinity, you should stop and read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  Then look at the definitions of `Double.NaN`, `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` in the Javadoc.  Hint: `NaN` is defined as `0.0d/0.0d`;

Comment: @JimGarrison Thank you Jim, I'll read the link and double check my code.

Answer (score 0):

"NaN" stands for "not a number". "Nan" is produced if a floating point operation(Double/Float) has some input parameters that cause the operation to produce some undefined result. For example, 0.0 divided by 0.0 is arithmetically undefined. Taking the square root of a negative number is also undefined.

NaN is static variable in Double and Float wrapper classes.It is Not a Numeric value so in Your Scenario, When you try to measure the distance between two coordinate it return Double.NaN, then It tries to convert it into a primitive number so it will give you a NullPointerException.

Comment: Primitive floats can hold NaN values just fine, no NPE is thrown.

Comment: So does it mean that there are some slices of codes having calculated double/0.0 so this NaN appear in the output?

Comment: @JimGarrison When I execute my codes there is no exception thrown, but when I step into the Object class, it indicates the NullPointerException is thrown but it still keeps executing.

Comment: @simons It would have to be 0.0/0.0; if it computes X/0.0 where X is non-zero, the result would be Inf or -Inf (infinity), not NaN.  Also, there are other operations that produce NaN besides 0/0.

Comment: @ajb Thank you ajb, I'll look into the library further to see what's wrong with my data.